# Flushleft bibliography APA style

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, apa-style

I need all the line in bibliography to be flush left. Following is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage[byname]{smartref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\cite{Gourvenec2003}
\cite{gourvenec2004}
\cite{gourvenec2008}
\cite{Gourvenec2011}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

\begin{FlushLeft}   
\bibliography{bib}{}
\end{FlushLeft}

\end{document}
```

My **bib** file contains

```
@article{Gourvenec2003,
  doi = {10.1680/geot.2003.53.6.575},
  year  = {2003},
  month = {Jan},
  publisher = {Thomas Telford Ltd.},
  volume = {53},
  number = {6},
  pages = {575--586},
  author = {S. Gourvenec and M. Randolph},
  title = {Effect of strength non-homogeneity on the shape of failure envelopes for combined loading of strip and circular foundations on clay},
  journal = {G{\'{e}}otechnique}
}



@article{gourvenec2008,
  doi = {10.1680/geot.2008.58.3.177},
  year  = {2008},
  month = {Jan},
  publisher = {Thomas Telford Ltd.},
  volume = {58},
  number = {3},
  pages = {177--185},
  author = {S. Gourvenec},
  title = {Effect of embedment on the undrained capacity of shallow foundations under general loading},
  journal = {G{\'{e}}otechnique}
}

@inproceedings{gourvenec2004,
  title={Bearing capacity under combined loading--a study of the effect of shear strength heterogeneity},
  author={Gourvenec, Susan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of 9th Australia New Zealand Conference on Geomechanics, Auckland,New Zealand},
  pages={527--533},
    date = {8--11},
    month = {Feb},
  year={2004}
}

@article{Gourvenec2011,
  doi = {10.1680/geolett.11.00026},
  year  = {2011},
  month = {Oct},
  publisher = {Thomas Telford Ltd.},
  volume = {1},
  number = {October-December},
  pages = {101--108},
  author = {Gourvenec, Susan and Mana, D. S. K},
  title = {Undrained vertical bearing capacity factors for shallow foundations},
  journal = {G{\'{e}}otechnique Letters}
}
```

And the output looks like:
[image]

The second and further lines after each references are not flush left. How can I do this? I have not specifically read the APA guidelines about this but making it flush left looks more aesthetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard way APA style bibliographies are formatted, since it makes the entries easier to distinguish from one another. But the margin in `apacite` is controlled by the length `\bibleftmargin` (see p.35 of the documentation).  You need to change both the left margin and the `\bibindent`:

```
\setlength{\bibleftmargin}{0pt}
\setlenght{\bibindent}{0pt}
```

will make the entries flush left.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\begin{FlushLeft}
\setlength{\bibindent}{0pt}
\bibliography{bib}{}
\end{FlushLeft}
```

If I use `\setlength{\bibleftmargin}{0pt}` then the left margin on first line of each of the references is made zero and it looks like
[image]

When I use the bibindent command, then it gets justified. However, as written earlier, the clarity is lost and it, indeed, does not look aesthetic. So I am sticking to the original suggested style in APA. @Alan Munn I am upvoting your answer since you told me that is the way originally APA bibliography is written.

Comment: I've updated my answer (I wasn't able to test it when I posted). Instead of using a `FlushLeft` environment, you can just set the `\bibleftmargin` to `0pt` and also the `\bibindent` to `0pt`.